# Return class literal as intersection type

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have couple of enums implementing some common interface and I would like to return class literal from the method. However I am unable to specify the intersection type correctly. See below the code sample illustrating the problem.

```
public class GenericsTest {    
  interface Iface {   
  }

  enum E1 implements Iface {    
  }

  enum E2 implements Iface {    
  }

  <E extends Enum<E> & Iface> Class<E> getEnum1() {
    return E1.class;  //ERROR incompatible types: java.lang.Class<GenericsTest.E1> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<E>
  }

  Class<? extends Enum<?>> getEnum3() {
    return E1.class;  //OK
  }

  Class<? extends Iface> getEnum4() {
    return E1.class;  //OK
  }

  <E extends Enum<E> & Iface> void enumParam(Class<E> p) {
    enumParam(E1.class);  //OK
  }

}
```

`#getEnum1` method doesn't compile. Interestingly it works as parameter value in `#enumParam`. How can I specify the intersection type to be able to return class literal from the method?

Comment: I think this is not related to multiple interfaces in a bounded wildcard generic type. It wouldn't compile even if the signature was only `<E extends Enum<E>> Class<E> getEnum1()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `getEnum1` does not compile for literally the same reason as this one:

```
public <E> E foo() {
    return "bar"; // Compile time error: Incompatible types E and String
}
```

See? Just because the type parameter `E` could be eventually a string, it does not mean it is *compatible* with `String`. One could call this function as `Integer i = x.<Integer>foo();`, so returning a string does not make sense here.

`getEnum1` is quite the same. Type parameter `E` could be choosen to be the type `E1` (very bad naming here), but it does not mean `E1` is always compatible with `E`. Consider `E2 e2 = x.<E2>getEnum1();`. You may wonder why the compiler doesn't just alert an error when one tries to call it with the wrong type parameter. The thing is, `E2` satisfies the type constraints, so there is just no reason to show an error there.

### So how can you make your code working?

Easiest (and possibly the only) way is to just get rid of generics there:

```
Class<E1> getEnum1() {
  return E1.class;
}
```

If you don't want to expose the concrete type `E1` here, you are out of luck. All you can do is to extract the common functionalities to an interface, and return that type.

Comment: well explained, thanks, I understand why it doesn't compile. So the solution would be to use wildcard type, however it is not possible to have wildcard type with intersection, as this is not allowed by Java language.

Comment: @saberduck And neither is there a syntax to define recursive wildcard types.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that there is no way your code would be guaranteed to return the right Class type instance given the context in which is use each time.
E.g.

```
final Class<E2> e2var = new GenericsTest().getEnum1();
```

The compiler fails at `getEnum1` to prevent a delayed run-time error when someone tries to do some `E2` bound operation on the object referred by e2var which is in fact always `Class<E1>`.

To propose a solution you need to be more specific of what is the intended use of this class set.

In contrast is not surprising that `enumParam` works as it does not need to return a matching class object. Yet, it is obvious that it would cause a stack-overflow due to an infinite recursion.

Comment: How it is then possible that `#getEnum3` and `#getEnum4` compile without problems? I don't see the difference between them and the intersection type with regards to guarantees provided to outside code?

Comment: @saberduck notice that getEnum3 and getEnum4 return type is not fixed by the calling context ... is just something that extends Class of an Enum or Iface respectively and E1.class does. Try to write a line of code that would assign its value to a E2 typed variable... you will need to cast them into E2 because from the using code stand point it only knows that it returns a Enum or Iface but it does not what is the actual class. In contrast with getEnum1 you don't have to cast because it it supposed to return an instance for the class of the receiving variable... but it does not compile.

Comment: I see your point, so the solution would be not to fix the type and put wildcard `?`, however it is not possible to have wildcard with intersection type